# My Book 500GB drive enclosure has failed; how can I access the drives?

Tags: hard-drive-recovery

My Western Digital My Book 500GB drive enclosure has failed. I've pulled both drives from the enclosure and have connected them by a USB SATA connector to my Windows 7 computer. The drives are recognized by Disk Management but Explorer is not an option (grayed out).

How can I access these drives?

Comment: Post a screenshot of Disk management, add it to your original post using edit.

Comment: has disk management assigned them a drive letter?

Comment: @Moab, he’s got 1-rep, so he can’t add a photo. John, you can still add the link to the photo as text.

Answer (score 0):

The WD 1G that I've owned, assuming the 500G is the same, had a block of data before the actual drive started.
Under Windows, I'm not sure how to skip over the first 512b of a drive. Find a computer using Linux, the losetup command for making a virtual disk, skipping over the first 512b of firmware.

Beyond that, the drive didn't seem to affect the data on the drive, just moved everything up 1 block.